# How to set a RewriteCond for a certain page URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have implemented a mod rewrite condition as shown below. Basically I want everyone other than me (from the stated IP address) to be redirected to a certain page on my site. That part works but these directives end up causing endless redirects and the browser times-out.

What might a RewriteCond directive look like to test the page `/index.html` and not do anymore rewrites if the page is https://example.com/index.html?

```
# 2016-03-18 redirect everyone except listed IPs
# 123.456.789.012 = my static Work Office address
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(123\.456\.789\.012)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/index.html [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to exclude the destination you are redirecting to :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(123\.456\.789\.012)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/index.html [R=302,L]
```

Otherwise you will get a redirect loop error because `index.htm` also matches the pattern `^(.*)$` .

Comment: Perfect @starkeen. Tested and it worked exactly as I needed. Thanks